# Navigation doubts in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have to pass a value from one view-controller to another view-controller,my this code works fine

```
NSString *localStringtextnote;

-(IBAction)_clickbtnsyncNote:(id)sender
{
localStringtextnote = textVieww.text;
        Googledocmainpage *detailViewController = [[Googledocmainpage alloc] initWithNibName:@"Googledocmainpage" bundle:nil];

        detailViewController.localStringtextnote = localStringtextnote;
        // ...
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

        [detailViewController release];
```

but i want to pass localStringtextnote through this way

```
Googledocmainpage *aSecondViewController = [[Googledocmainpage alloc] initWithNibName:@"Googledocmainpage" bundle:nil];
    aSecondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:aSecondViewController animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:aSecondViewController animated:YES];
```

how to pass a value through the above page rediriction method?i hope u understand my question.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  like this

```
Googledocmainpage *aSecondViewController = [[Googledocmainpage alloc] initWithNibName:@"Googledocmainpage" bundle:nil];

aSecondViewController.localStringtextnote = localStringtextnote;

    aSecondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:aSecondViewController animated:YES];
   // [self.navigationController pushViewController:aSecondViewController animated:YES];
```

also why are you using both way (pushing the view and presentModelView , use only one in a time).